# Using R to find the smallest combination of columns that gives unique combination

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with around 2500 named columns, each with 43 named rows. Each element of each row contains one of two possible text values unique to the row, or a blank. I would like to find the smallest combination of columns that would give me a unique, non-blank heterologous pair of values per row. I am most familiar with R, so a solution for that would be the best.

To illustrate in down-sized version of the challenge:

```
> l <- data.frame(C1 = c("a","i","","y"), C2 = c("b","i","q","x"), C3 = c("b","","p",""), C4 = c("b","j","q","y"), C5 = c("a","","p",""), C6 = c("b","i","q","x"))
> l
   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
R1  a  b  b  b  a  b
R2  i  i     j     i
R3     q  p  q  p  q
R4  y  x     y  x  x
>
```

The smallest combination of unique columns would then be: `C1, C4, C5`:

```
   C1 C4 C5 
R1  a  b  a  
R2  i  j     
R3     q  p  
R4  y  y  x   
>
```

This will give the unique pairs:

```
   Pair
R1   ab
R2   ij
R3   pq
R4   xy
```

I estimate that I might be able to achieve a unique combination of pairs using three or four columns (already tried two using Excel). The problem is that the number of possible combinations is huge (billions in case of three columns required: 2500*2500*2500 and trillions for more than three). Hence I don't think `comb()` or `expand.grid` is going to work as the dataframe will be too large.

In the end, I think this problem is perhaps similar to an optimisation problem of the shortest-path type, it might not be easy to resolve in a reasonable amount of computer time, but I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing exactly and why you're trying to do it.  With that said you have some inconsistencies in your example that you might want to clean up: R4 doesn't contain x,  You say C6 but then use C5, etc...

Comment: To add to @Dason what is the output you're trying to get to? Do you want to know the actual columns C1, C4, C5, or are you trying to get to the unique pairs?

Comment: @Dason, you're right, corrected.

Comment: @ Eric Watt, ultimately my only interest is finding a combination that will give me a unique pair for all 43 rows

Comment: I can easily code a brute force approach (even in compiled code using Rcpp) but if you are looking for a better algorithm (and I agree that you need one) you'll need to ask a mathematician.

Comment: @Roland. You're probably right. A brute force approach may simply take too long.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do. At the end of the day if there are only two possible values besides blanks that a row can have and you don't appear to take order into consideration when making your "pair" then how is the pair anything more than just the two possible values in the row pasted together?

Comment: @Dason. It's a bit tricky to explain without context, which I'm afraid I am not at liberty to reveal. It is true that the pairs are the two possible values in the rows pasted together, but these have to be compiled from columns for which the values and blanks are fixed. The order of the rows is irrelevant here. With the collection of columns I have, which ones should I choose to cover all paired values to allow me to do this with the minimum amount of columns?

Comment: So is your question really "Can we find a minimal subset of columns such that each row in this subset contains both of the unique values for that particular row?"

Comment: And we need to find the subset of the columns vs. finding a different way to generate those pairs?

Comment: @Dason That is indeed a much better way of phrasing it. We're unfortunately limited to the columns we have. These are fixed

Comment: Well I meant do you definitely need to go this route vs scanning a row until you find two unique values then moving to the next row and repeating...

Comment: @Dason, I don't think that will yield the smallest number of columns. I reckon this may be quite a computationally difficult problem. The brute force approach would involve trying every combination, but that could get rather crazy with >2 columns

Comment: @Svencken - I know it won't. But that's why I was asking - why is the smallest column approach necessary? Is the ultimate goal to get the unique pairings or to get the columns?

Comment: @Dason, it is important to get the unique parings. However, this has to be done with the minimum amount of columns. With some manual work I have managed to do this with 7 columns, but I'm guessing this is possible with 6.
This question relates to a real world (genetic) situation.